# How to define sequence of my cucumber tests

Tags: java, cucumber

I have multiple feature files in my Cucumber tests, such as feature1, feature2, and feature3.

Our framework is set to enable parallel test execution by default.
However, the execution of feature3 could potentially affect feature1 and feature2.

How can I prioritize running feature1 and feature2 first, followed by feature3?